# select all the values between two days independently from the year in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, mask, datetimeindex

Let's say that I have the following dataframe:

```
dates,qq
1900-01-01,1
1900-01-02,2
1900-01-03,3
1900-01-04,4
1900-01-05,5
1900-01-06,6
1900-01-07,7
1901-01-01,8
1901-01-02,9
1901-01-03,10
1901-01-04,11
1901-01-05,12
1901-01-06,13
1901-01-07,14
1902-01-01,15
1902-01-02,16
1902-01-03,17
1902-01-04,18
1902-01-05,19
1902-01-06,20
1902-01-07,21
1903-12-30,22
1903-12-31,23
```

Firstly, I have read the dataframe as:

```
dfr = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
```

Now I would like selected all the values around a specific day of the year but independently from the year.

Let's say that I have selected the first of January and a +- delta of 2 days:

```
delta_d = pd.Timedelta(2., unit='d') 
dates   = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1400', end='1/1/1401')
day_c = dates[0]
```

A good idea could be to create a mask. I have tried the following:

```
mask = (dfr.index.day>= day_c.day) & (dfr.index.day < day_c.day+delta_d)
```

However, as I could have expected, I get the following error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Cannot cast 1400-01-01 00:00:00 to unit='ns' without overflow.
```

I expect the following result:

```
res = [1,2,3,8,9,10,15,16,17,22,23]
```

Comment: According to your problem description, 22 should not be in the expected result, @diedro.

Comment: You are right. I have edit as consequence my questions by adding a +-delta and by changing some dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
# For each row, s is Jan 1 of the same year
s = pd.to_datetime(
    pd.DataFrame({"year": df.index.year, "month": 1, "day": 1})
).to_numpy()

start_date = s - pd.Timedelta(days=2)
end_date = s + pd.Timedelta(days=2)

# Filtering
df[(start_date <= df.index) & (df.index <= end_date)]
```

Comment: It looks to be the right direction. I had make myself not clear. Looks, please, to my edit version of the questions.

Comment: You can just tweak the code to generate `start_date` and `end_date`. See my edited answer

Comment: The start_date seems not working. There is an additional year in the shifting.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
dfr[[x == 1 and y in range(1, 4) for x, y in zip(dfr.index.month, dfr.index.day)]]
```

Output:

```
            qq
dates         
1900-01-01   1
1900-01-02   2
1900-01-03   3
1901-01-01   8
1901-01-02   9
1901-01-03  10
1902-01-01  15
1902-01-02  16
1902-01-03  17
```

Comment: I am sorry. Thanks to your previous comment I have up-dated my question by adding a +-delta.

Comment: With negative deltas, I would recommend using @CodeDifferent's solution, which is more suitable for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try This approach, it is working for delta days ahead. You just have to work it out for delta days behind.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'dates': ['1900-01-01', '1900-01-02', '1900-01-03', '1900-01-04', '1900-01-05', '1900-01-06', '1900-01-07',
              '1901-01-01', '1901-01-02', '1901-01-03', '1901-01-04', '1901-01-05', '1901-01-06', '1901-01-07',
              '1902-01-01', '1902-01-02', '1902-01-03', '1902-01-04', '1902-01-05', '1902-01-06', '1902-01-07',
              '1903-12-30', '1903-12-31'],
    'qq': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

# Define target date and delta
target_date_str = '01-01'
delta = pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')

# Filter the DataFrame based on the target date and delta
mask = ((df['dates'].dt.month == pd.to_datetime(target_date_str, format='%m-%d').month) &
        (df['dates'].dt.day.between(pd.to_datetime(target_date_str, format='%m-%d').day - delta.days,
                                    pd.to_datetime(target_date_str, format='%m-%d').day + delta.days)))
result = df.loc[mask, 'qq'].tolist()

print(result)
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17]